# C# convert JSON to a JArray for an upload to Algolia

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, algolia

With the Algolia online cloud search engine their examples work fine.

```
// Load JSON file  ( from file system )
StreamReader re = File.OpenText("contacts.json");
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(re);
JArray batch = JArray.Load(reader);
// Add objects
Index index = client.InitIndex("contacts");
index.AddObjects(batch);
```

So what I am wanting to do it take C# class of properties that I serialized to JSON and be able to somehow use it as a JArray to load and add to send to Algolia.

```
// works fine
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(boom);
JArray batch = JArray.Parse(json);  // breaks

Index index = client.InitIndex("myindex");
index.AddObjects(batch);
```

This breaks

```
JArray batch = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Comment: What is exception?

Comment: it is putting in backslashes  for one thing      `"{\"FileName\":\"EUR_SEQ_123989.txt\",\"body\":\"HDR;123989;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\\r\\5:31:34 AM;"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely failing because `boom` is not an array. What you can do is put `boom` in an anonymous array, and serialize that instead:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new[] { boom });
var batch = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Even better, you can skip over the serialization and create the `JArray` immediately from your object:

`var batch = JArray.FromObject(new[] { boom });`